# jQuery: get the file name selected from <input type="file" />

Tags: jquery, events, copy, file-io

This code should work **in IE** (don't even test it in Firefox), but it doesn't.
What I want is to display the name of the attached file. Any help?

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>example</title>    
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">  
        $(document).ready( function(){            
      $("#attach").after("<input id='fakeAttach' type='button' value='attach a file' />");      
      $("#fakeAttach").click(function() {            
        $("#attach").click();        
        $("#maxSize").after("<div id='temporary'><span id='attachedFile'></span><input id='remove' type='button' value='remove' /></div>");        
        $('#attach').change(function(){
          $("#fakeAttach").attr("disabled","disabled");          
          $("#attachedFile").html($(this).val());
        });        
        $("#remove").click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $("#attach").replaceWith($("#attach").clone());
          $("#fakeAttach").attr("disabled","");
          $("#temporary").remove();
        });
      })
    }); 
  </script> 
</head>
<body>
  <input id="attach" type="file" /><span id="maxSize">(less than 1MB)</span>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check my answer, I believe it's the best and most understandable way of achieving this.

Answer (score 148):

It is just such simple as writing:

```
$('input[type=file]').val()
```

Anyway, I suggest using name or ID attribute to select your input.
And with event, it should look like this:

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function(e){
  $in=$(this);
  $in.next().html($in.val());
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked on the previous (and simplified) problem I posed, but it doen't work on the extended version.

Comment: how to get the complete path of the file the above code only gives the file name.

Comment: @PHP Priest, you can't. Browsers don't expose that kind of information.

Comment: @PHP Priest, if you could do that, you could surreptitiously transmit data about the user's file system via AJAX and the user would likely never know.  Imagine how much worse it would be if you could programmatically *set* the value of a file input.  Yeah.  Security issues.

Comment: @emrah I think it is a convention to indicate that the variable hold a jquery object instead of a plain dom object

Comment: @DanRoberts I ment where does it come from. I figured later it is weird local js var.

Comment: @Thinker Is there a way to set the name of a file before it it sent to server. Thanks.

Comment: This seems a bit over the top? The way I've listed is a lot easier and understandable.

Comment: @User You cannot set the filename of the file, first it would change the file being uploaded and second you cannot change input type file values.

Answer (score 20):

The simplest way is to simply use the following line of `jquery`, using this you don't get the `/fakepath` nonsense, you straight up get the file that was uploaded:

```
$('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]; // This gets the file
$('#idOfFileUpload')[0].files[0]; // This gets the file with the specified id
```

***Some other useful commands are:***

To get the name of the file:

```
$('input[type=file]')[0].files[0].name; // This gets the file name
```

To get the type of the file:

If I were to upload a PNG, it would return `image/png`

```
$("#imgUpload")[0].files[0].type
```

To get the size (in bytes) of the file:

```
$("#imgUpload")[0].files[0].size
```

Also you don't have to use these commands `on('change'`, you can get the values at any time, for instance you may have a file upload and when the user clicks `upload`, you simply use the commands I listed.

Comment: why did i get error Cannot read property 'name' of undefined?

Answer (score 19):

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function(e){
    $(this).parents('.parent-selector').find('.element-to-paste-filename').text(e.target.files[0].name);
});
```

This code will not show `C:\fakepath\` before file name in Google Chrome in case of using `.val()`.

Answer (score 4):

```
<input onchange="readURL(this);"  type="file" name="userfile" />
<img src="" id="blah"/>
<script>
 function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result)
                    .width(150).height(200);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        //console.log(reader);
        //alert(reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]));
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks!  This was helpful in grabbing the actual name of the file uploaded and not the full path.

Answer (score 3):

I had used following which worked correctly.

```
$('#fileAttached').attr('value', $('#attachment').val())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//get file input
var $el = $('input[type=file]');
//set the next siblings (the span) text to the input value 
$el.next().text( $el.val() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden reset button :

```
<input id="Reset1" type="reset" value="reset" class="hidden" />
```

Click the reset button to clear the input.

```
$("#Reset1").click();
```

Comment: Can you click a hidden button?

Answer (score -1):

```
<input onchange="readURL(this);"  type="file" name="userfile" />
<img src="" id="viewImage"/>
<script>
 function readURL(fileName) {
    if (fileName.files && fileName.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#viewImage')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result)
                    .width(150).height(200);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(fileName.files[0]);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks man i was searching for this i know this is not the subject but it was my answer you know ;)