# How do I use JQuery to detect if a file input has a file selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

And then alert the file name?

Comment: $('#inputfile').on('change', function (e) {
           alert(e.val());
});

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This should suffice:

```
alert($('#your_input_box').val());
```

A file selection box is just an input box, from what I can tell. Read more from this question: [jQuery: get the file name selected from <input type="file" />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299052/jquery-get-the-file-name-selected-from-input-typefile).

Answer (score 22):

To detect if a file was selected, you can find out the length of the file input

```
$("#bCheck").click(function() { // bCheck is a input type button
    var fileName = $("#file1").val();

    if(fileName) { // returns true if the string is not empty
        alert(fileName + " was selected");
    } else { // no file was selected
        alert("no file selected");
    }
});
```

Comment: Why does if(fileName) returns true? I just tested it and it works fine, I just don't understand why it returns true when the value is actual path of the file selected in string format.

Comment: @Usce if a string has a value it's truthy in javascript.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this topic @SeanT

Comment: This will not work as described. This is triggered when you click on the 'browse' button, and the value is checked BEFORE a file is selected. It will always come back with 'no file selected', unless a file was already selected.