# How to capture the filename from a file input using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, file, file-upload

I have a form that has a file input control:

```
<input type="file" onclick="this.blur()" name="descFile" />
```

So when the user selects a file, the path shows in the text input box (default browser behaviour), BUT, the business would like me to put a message in bold letters below that they have selected the file to be uploaded, *prior to postback*.

Is there a way using Javascript to somehow capture the "select" event from file input and display in bold letters below the file input?

Comment: Do you want to capture the filename, or just the fact that he selected a file?

Comment: Just that they selected a file.  It's odd since I thought the browser control was intuitive enough, but I guess our users need more indication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('input[name="descFile"]').change(function(){
   var filename = $(this).val();
   $('<label>Filename selected: '+ filename +'</label>').insertAfter($(this));
});
```

Remember to put it inside or similar to:

```
$(function(){ });
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great.  Not sure why the users need more of an indication, but that's how it goes. :)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done like this

```
$('input[type=file]').val()
```

Anyway, I suggest using name or ID attribute to select your input. And with event, it should look like this:

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function(e){
  $in=$(this);
  $in.next().html($in.val());
});
```

Comment: You should give credit to the person who wrote this originally: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299052/jquery-get-the-file-name-selected-from-input-type-file

Answer (score 1):

It's the **value** attrib of your input tag, if I understand your question.

```
$('#file_attach').change(function(){

        path=$(this).attr('value');
        start = path.lastIndexOf(".");
        alert("extention: "+start);
});
```