# jquery file selected not working in IE

Tags: jquery, if-statement

Hi i'm writing file selected using jquery , its working in all browsers but in IE it return false

Please help how im getting this issue ,My code shown as below

```
$("#Button").click(function(){

    if(fileSelected($("#file1"))&&fileSelected($("#file2")))
    {
      //do something
    }
    else{          
      return false;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: We cannot say much without seeing the implementation of `fileSelected()`. Can you post it in your question?

Comment: whar are these file1 and file2 (i.e dropdown or radio etc...)

Answer (score 0):

It is solved differently in another question: [jQuery: get the file name selected from <input type="file" />](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299052/762846) Does this work for you? If the val in that answer is an empty string it means no file is selected.

Comment: Answering with solely a reference to another answer is not ok. This should be a comment!

Comment: I can't add comments yet, but will do when I can. Thanks for the instructions.