# Get form input filename using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to check the name of the file before the user hits submit. Can I get the filename like we get the content of the input field?

Something like:

```
<input name="posterTitle" type="text" ng-model="posterTitle">
{{posterTitle}}
```

Similarly in:

```
<input name="posterFileName" ng-model="posterFileName" type="file" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Angularjs you might need to use an onchange event to bind the input name inside controller. see the example :

```
<input name="posterFileName" type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileName(this)"/>
```

Inside controller

```
$scope.fileName= function(element) {
   $scope.$apply(function($scope) {
      $scope.posterTitle= element.files[0].name;
   });
};
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

a couple of links I've found that may help a bit:
http://api.jquery.com/file-selector/
[jQuery: get the file name selected from <input type="file" />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299052/jquery-get-the-file-name-selected-from-input-type-file)

for example, sing name or ID attribute:

$('input[type=file]').change(function(e){
  $in=$(this);
  $in.next().html($in.val());
});

Comment: I was actually looking for an angular approach. I need to make comparisons with the filename in my angular controller.