# Change the default style of input file and change the text after select a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, file, input

I want to change the default style of input file, I searched SO and find a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button).
http://jsfiddle.net/younyzhU/6v8uL2co/

```
<div id=customOrth style="position: absolute; left:0; top:0px; ">
<button><label for="inputFile" style="padding-left: 0px;">
<a >choose orthology File</a></label></button>
<input style="display: none;" type="file" id="inputFile">
</div>
```

However when I select a file, I need to change the label to the selected file name, how should I do?
The default input file, will show you the choosed file name, after select a file.
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer should help you, https://stackoverflow.com/a/1299069/3066711

It should be as simple as something like this.

```
$("#inputFile").on("change", function(data) { $("label[for=inputFile]").text($(this).val())});
```