# Why is my input type=file not loading file information?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to get my head around this. I have an `<input type='file'>` element which is being used to upload files as an alternative to a drag and drop option for users with older browsers.

The drag and drop upload works fine, but for some reason when selecting files using the input, the `files` object returns `undefined`.

In the example below I've included a test variable to check that the event listener is working - which it is - but the attempts to log the contents of the file are not working - whether I try to log the full object or an individual property.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
 <input type="file" id='uploadFile'>
```

Javascript (jQuery)

```
 doc.on('change', '#uploadFile', function(){
    var file = $(this);
    var test = 'Event Triggered';
    console.log(test);               //Returns 'Event Triggered'
    console.log(file.files);         //Returns undefined
    console.log(file.files[0]);      //Returns TypeError: cannot read property '0' of undefined
 });
```

Where am I going wrong? Can't help but feel that this is a stupid oversight somewhere but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading file contents on the client-side in javascript in various browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750032/reading-file-contents-on-the-client-side-in-javascript-in-various-browsers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
doc.on('change', '#uploadFile', function(e){
    var file = $(this);
    var test = 'Event Triggered';
console.log(e.target.files)

 });
```

Use event.target.files

Comment: All good answers, but I liked this one the best as it looks the cleanest. - thanks everyone!

Answer (score 6):

The `files` property is on the DOMElement, not a jQuery object. Try this:

```
$(document).on('change', '#uploadFile', function() {
    var file = $(this)[0]; // note the [0] to return the DOMElement from the jQuery object
    var test = 'Event Triggered';

    console.log(test);
    console.log(file.files);
    console.log(file.files[0]);
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/n3jr9dmq/)

Answer (score 3):

It is my solution:

```
$('#uploadFile').change(function()
{
   console.log(this.files);         
   console.log(this.files[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try this `console.log($('#uploadFile')[0].files[0]);`

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299052/jquery-get-the-file-name-selected-from-input-type-file) Hope this helps