# Validate input file when it come null

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this input file:

Razor:

```
@Html.TextBox("archivo", "", new { type = "file",id = "archivo" }
```

Html:

```
<input id="archivo" name="archivo" type="file" value="">
```

I want to capture message if value of input is null when I press button:

`<button type="button" id="btnCargarCsv"  class="btn btn-primary">Cargar</button>`

So on clic function I try to send message as:

```
 $("#btnCargarCsv").on("click", function () {
        if ($('#archivo').val() == null) {
            $('#resultado').html('you need to select file');
        }
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("archivo", $("#archivo")[0].files[0]);

        $.ajax({
            "type": "POST",
            "url": "/Configuracion/CargaCSV",
               ...
```

But it just don't throw message when input come null beacuse it don't hit:

`$('#resultado').html('you need to select file');`

like input is not null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can simply use `if ($('#archivo').val()) { // ajax call } else { // display message }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verify using blank string instead of null..

Also look into : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript) for difference between null and empty

And Possible : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299052/jquery-get-the-file-name-selected-from-input-type-file)

```
$("#btnCargarCsv").on("click", function () {

    if ($('#archivo').val() == '') {
        $('#resultado').html('you need to select file');
        return;
    }

    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("archivo", $("#archivo")[0].files[0]);

    $.ajax({
        "type": "POST",
        "url": "/Configuracion/CargaCSV",
            ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Check Length.

```
if ($('#archivo').get(0).files.length === 0) {
       $('#resultado').html('you need to select file');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try ..!

```
 if ($('#archivo').get(0).files.length === 0) {
        //console.log("No files selected.");
        //alert("Please select file..");
         $('#resultado').html('you need to select file');

    }
```

Hope this helps..!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why your code isnt working. But the file validation (null or not) can be done by simply adding a *required* tag to your html.

```
<input... [whatever be your type and value].. required/>
```

Validation would be done by this piece of code.

Maybe its not null,, try it with "" and check...

```
if($('#archivo').val()=="")
{
      //print your message
}
else
      //your logic goes here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Just check if a variable has a true value or not. In your case it will be

```
if(!$('#archivo').val()) {
  $('#resultado').html('you need to select file');
    return;
}
```

It will evaluate to false if value is **false, 0, empty string, NaN, undefined, null**